# Highcharts on zeppelin 0.6.0 executes but does not display any chart

Tags: highcharts, apache-zeppelin

I am using zeppelin 0.6.0 (zeppelin-0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT from Hortonworks) and wanted to try out highcharts. So I followed the [link](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts/blob/master/docs/UseInZeppelin.md) to setup my zeppelin. However the zeppelin UI did not have option to add the dependency. So, I made change to the zeppelin configuration file and added the following after copying the jar files - spark-highcharts-0.6.0.jar,
lift-json_2.10-2.6.3.jar and paranamer-2.4.1.jar.

```
export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=8g -Dspark.cores.max=16 --packages com.knockdata:zeppelin-highcharts-0.6.0"
```

I ran the tutorial notebook in zeppelin and loaded the data. 
As per the instructions, I executed java script which ran without any error.

```
    %angular
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        if (typeof Highcharts == "undefined") {
            $.getScript("http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js")
              .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
                console.log( "load http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js " + textStatus );
              })
              .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
                 console.log("load http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js " + exception);
              });
        } else {
            console.log("highcharts already loaded");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then I ran the following to plot data which ran fine but there was nothing to plot. Also checked browser console and it did not show any error. Interestingly the java script which i ran earlier did not show any message in browser console too (Expected "highcharts already loaded" message in the console).

```
%spark 
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts.model._

highcharts(bank.series("x" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("balance")))
.orderBy(col("age"))).plot()
```

Please let me know what is missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This might sound weird but it looks like an issue with Chrome. While experimenting, I started chrome in Incognito mode and ran the highcharts again. This time it showed the chart. Later I cleared the history in Chrome and ran in regular mode.I was able to see the plot. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: You are right. This helps. Try using incognito mode and switching browser before concluding the issue is with graph.